# Greedy search for string patterns using regular expressions in Java

Tags: java, regex, pattern-matching

I have a use case where I want to search for a operator amongst <,>,<=,>=, and = in a given string and split the expression into 2 parts i.e. the right expression and the left expression and evaluate them individually before evaluating the final conditional operator.

This can be understood from the example below:

```
Pattern pattern1 = Pattern.compile("(.*?)(<|>|<=|=|>=)(.*)");
Matcher matcher2 = pattern1.matcher("4>=5");
while (matcher2.find()) {
        System.out.println(matcher2.group(1) + ";" + matcher2.group(2)+ ";" + matcher2.group(3));
}
```

Output:

```
4;>;=5
```

The expected output was `4;>=;5` but the `>=` operator got split because of the presence of the operator `>` independently.

I want to evaluate the clause `(<|>|<=|=|>=)` in a greedy fashion so that `>=` gets treated as a single entity and gets listed down if they occur together.

Comment: Just put them in the right order ... (<=|>=|=|>|<).  That should do what you want.

Comment: @RobertHanson - Thats a good one. It worked but what if I am getting a list of these operators from a list. In that case, I may not be sure of the order. How do I make it independent of the order?

Comment: @RobertHanson: You should post that as an answer!

Comment: @AbhishekJain - You could sort them by length first.  E.g.  Collections.sort(listOfOperators, lengthComparator), where lengthComparator is an instance of Comparator that has been implemented to sort by length.

Comment: @RobertHanson - Thanks for suggesting that but I have already implemented the same using the same technique. Anyways, thanks for posting this. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
String testt = "4>=5";
System.out.println(testt.replaceAll("(.*?)(>=?|<=?|=)(.*)", "$1;$2;$3"));
```

Easy to understand and you will replace all at once. You had a mistake that would stop getting <= if it finds a < before it, so just place those 2 <= and >= to the first places.

Comment: same comment as I made to other answers as well : what if I am getting the operator list from an unsorted data structure. I may not be able to express the same without knowing all the operators.

Comment: So why not make a (operator1|operator2) string (runtime) and then attach it to the regex? `"(.*?)"+operators+"(.*)"`

Comment: exactly what I am trying to do but 1) I may not be sure of the order in which the operators come in from the unsorted data structure so, the order may well be <,>,<=,>= and thus the same problem. 2) I want to make it a dynamic thing where the operators may not be inter-related.

Comment: Yes, even I was thinking about that option. Let me give it a try. :)

Comment: But this would be an ugly implementation. Can we not do something smarter?

Comment: We solved your exercise, we told you how could do the variable operators and now you tell us that is an ugly implementation?, dude do something like `String operators=sortOperators(getOperators());`

Comment: I am sorry if you felt that I didn't appreciate your help but I do. The only concern is that is sounds more like a hack and not a proper way of doing it. Anyways, thanks for the answer.

Comment: If you dont know the operators you will have to do something to get them, if operators can't be in a random order, you will have to sort them.

Answer (score 2):

you can try simplifying to

```
 pattern1 = Pattern.compile("(.*?)(>=?|<=?|=)(.*)");
```

Comment: +1 Nice simplification rather. But this doesn't work for `4=5`.

Comment: @shyam - what if I am getting the operator list from an unsorted data structure. I may not be able to express the same without knowing all the operators.

Comment: @AbhishekJain Then you should not use regular expressions. What if one of your operators had a character that has special meaning as a regex?

Comment: @RohitJain Thanks :) missed the `=` in all those pipes